# Translate Delegate VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to translate a delegate from `VB.net` to `C#`. 1:1 Translation gives me error message

```
Delegate Sub DelegateListViewItem(ByRef item As ListViewItem)

CanMsgListView.Invoke(New DelegateListViewItem(AddressOf AddListViewItem), New ListViewItem(astrItems))
```

```
public Delegate void DelegateListViewItem(ref ListViewItem item);

CanMsgListView.Invoke(new DelegateListViewItem(AddListViewItem), new ListViewItem(astrItems));
```

- invalid token: void
- not declared as abstract, extern, partial
- type or namespace not found

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can remove the `ref` keyword. As ListViewItem is a class, it will automatically be passed by reference.

Comment: @johey That's wrong. [Read this for details.](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: This is just a casing issue, as often with VB > C#: `public delegate void DelegateListViewItem(ref ListViewItem item);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator) not [`Delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate) (which is a class in System):

```
public delegate void DelegateListViewItem(ref ListViewItem item);
```

Comment: So it is just a typo. I would personally vote to close instead.

Comment: Indeed, will do.